# Interpret GLM Output (Gaussian - identity) with B0 close to zero

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I am doing a GLM (guassian - identity) using R.  I am modeling different variables (8) to try to understand what creates brand value in an organization.
Some extracts from the output are:

```
Null deviance: 74.343  on 81  degrees of freedom  
Residual deviance: 32.870  on 69  degrees of freedom  
(19 observations deleted due to missingness)  
AIC: 185.75
```

I get that one of the coefficients is not significant (B0):

```
Intercept: Estimate   Std.Err. t value  Pr(>|t|)
           0.005959   0.109103   0.055  0.956602
```

However, some of the other variables are significant.  For example:

```
Consumer_attitude_1: Estimate   StdErr. t value Pr(>|t|)
                     0.512708  0.115864   4.425 3.52e-05  

Consumer_attitute_2: Estimate   StdErr. t value Pr(>|t|)  
                    -0.385588  0.152224  -2.533 0.013585
```

Based on these results, Would it be valid to say that the variables shown as significant in the model may have an impact on brand value even when B0 is close to zero?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The expected value of the response still changes as each of those variables changes, whether or not the intercept is zero.